# SQL Trigger Bad Bind Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will fire if the `Prog_Type` = `'EPISODE'`. I am receiving a bad binding error - PLS - 000049. I believe there is something wrong with my `DECLARE` state

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Seas_Pk_Trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Seas_ID ON Season_Table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
Prog_Type VARCHAR2(7);
BEGIN
IF (:OLD.Prog_Type <> 'EPISODE')
THEN SELECT Seas_ID_Seq.nextval into :new.Seas_ID from dual;
END IF;
END Seas_Pk_Trigger;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referencing a column in your table, you do not need to declare the column `Prog_Type` to reference it with a `:OLD` or `:NEW` pseudo-record. If `Prog_Type` is in your table (which I assume it is), then just omit the declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Seas_Pk_Trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Seas_ID ON Season_Table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:OLD.Prog_Type <> 'EPISODE')
THEN SELECT Seas_ID_Seq.nextval into :new.Seas_ID from dual;
END IF;
END Seas_Pk_Trigger;
/
```

I'm not sure how to interpret your statement that you only want this to fire when `Prog_Type = 'EPISODE'` as your trigger has a `<>` to EPISODE clause?

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code to what you recommend without the declare statement, but i am still receive the same binding error. Is it an error with the IF (:OLD.Prog_Type <> 'EPISODE') ? `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Seas_Pk_Trigger`  `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Seas_ID ON Season_Table`  `FOR EACH ROW`  `BEGIN`  `IF (:OLD.Prog_Type <> 'EPISODE')`  `THEN SELECT Seas_ID_Seq.nextval into :new.Seas_ID from dual;`  `END IF;`  `END Seas_Pk_Trigger;`  `/`

Comment: I tried creating your table, sequence and trigger exactly as shown, but I had no problem with a bad bind, and the trigger compiled just fine as stated. Are you sure the bad bind applies to this object? Do you have other DDL statements in your script? What IDE are you using? Or are you using SQL Plus?

Comment: Hi, I am using Oracle 11g. I dropped all my constraints and tables and rebuilt it. I set up the tables, then the constraints, and then this one trigger described above. However i receive this bad bind variable error 00049 on `(:OLF.Prog_Type)`. As mentioned above `Prog_Type` column is in the `Program_Table` not the `Season_Table`, so is the reason it cannot bind the variable is because it cannot find the variable, i.e. i need to reference the `Program_Table` ?

Comment: The trigger pseudo-records `:old` and `:new` **only** reference the table on which you created your trigger, not other tables. I didn't see any mention of a `program_table`? You can select from other tables in your trigger and then conditionally do something.

Comment: Thanks @Wolf, have changed to reference the Program_Table, and now it works correctly